# Gmail Oauth API get messages count

Tags: php, google-oauth, gmail-api

The new Gmail API now allows a message count for total emails and unread emails within a label.  But I can't get it to work and tried lots of things.  It's connected to Oauth correctly but can't get the count to work.  I'm using the below code:-

```
$labelall = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels('me');
        $labels = $labelall->getLabels();
     foreach ($labels as $label) {
         print 'Label with ID: ' . $label->getId() . ', 
Number of Messages:'.$label->getMessagesTotal().'<br/>';}
```

Can anyone help? It lists the labels correctly but message count returns null.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all fields are always set from a list() response--in this case, you have to do Labels.Get() on the label you care about to get the counts.